# Colocar vírgula entre as palavras

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou trazendo o resultado de um campo dinâmico do qual capturo da seguinte forma:

```
$c = 0;
    foreach($xml->avaliacao->respostas as $listar => $valor) {
      $respostas = $_POST["respostas"][$c];
$c++;    
}
```

Com isso ele me traz:

> A B C D

Gostaria de colocar vírgula entre os resultados.

> A,B,C,D

Sei que o implode faz isso, mas como eu usaria nesse caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso, `$respostas` vai ser sempre o último elemento - no caso **D** - pois está havendo uma reescrita da variável `$respostas`. O primeiro loop contém **A**, no segundo ela muda para **B**... assim por diante até o último.

Use `$respostas` como `array`, assim cada `$_POST["respostas"][$c]` conterá um índice no array. Depois basta usar `implode` para juntar o array com as devidas virgulas.

---

Fiz um exemplo no [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/17IwZF), o output é `Resposta A, Resposta B, Resposta C, Resposta D`. Desconsidere os array's, são apenas para ilustração do uso do implode.

```
$c = 0;
$POST = array( 'Resposta A' , 'Resposta B' , 'Resposta C' , 'Resposta D' );

foreach( array( 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' ) as $listar => $valor)
{
    $respostas[] = $POST[$c];
    $c++;    
}

echo implode( ', ' , $respostas );
```